# IndentXML for sublime text

Tags: xml, sublimetext2

So I have Sublime Text 2 and Indent XML on a Mac.  I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut which will will properly format the XML from a single line into a pretty print format.  The command I'm finding is command-k command f.  This is doing not what is expected, it's removing tags instead of formatting.  Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  I was not able to get this working on my Mac at home, but was able to at work on WIN7.  I tried overriding the default(OSX).sublime-keymap and still nothing.  I will be upgrading to Maverick here shortly.  Maybe it will work then, but I doubt it.

Comment: I was able to get this working on my PC at work.  Hopefully I will have some insight for when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to chalk it up to a bug for Mac OSX.  Since it works on Win7, and I've tried everything on my Mac.  If I have time this Dec/Jan I will pull the repo and see if I can figure it out if it hasn't been fixed by then.